# how to move one direction in UIScrollView when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm new in objective-c. I create `UIScrollView` object and add in my view with this code:

```
height = self.view.frame.size.height;
width = self.view.frame.size.width;

scrollbar = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
scrollbar.delegate = self;
scrollbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
scrollbar.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollbar.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollbar.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollbar.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollbar.pagingEnabled = YES;
[scrollbar setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width*4, height*4)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollbar];

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    first = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    first.view.frame = CGRectMake((i-1)*width, 0, width, height*4);
    [scrollbar addSubview:first.view];

    switch (i) {
          ase 1:
              first.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
              break;
          case 2:
              first.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
              break;
          case 3:
              first.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
              break;
          case 4:
              first.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
              break;
          default:
              break;
        }
    }
```

in my code I add 4 view in my ScrollView with different color now I want when scrolling on my ScrollView detect dx & dy (dx: driving distance on Axis.x & dy:driving distance on Axis.y) and check these two variable and when :

Notic: I want when any one touch on ScrollView and moving touch on Axis (x or y) or touch on Both Axis (x and y) check this :

**if (dx > dy) disable horizontal scroll and moving in vertical side!!!
else moving in horizontal side and disable vertical scroll!!!**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y, scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height);

    NSLog(@"%f,%f",visibleRect.origin.x,visibleRect.origin.y);

    /*NSLog(@"x : %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"y : %f",scrollView.contentOffset.y);*/
    if (fabsf(scrollView.contentOffset.x) > fabsf(scrollView.contentOffset.y)) {
        NSLog(@"Vertical Side");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Horizontal Side");
    }
}
```

please guide me guys. I can't disable one side and move another side!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want adding some code to your delegate. This is my `ViewController.m` file. `-viewDidLoad`, `#import` statements and the other methods are omitted.

```
@interface ViewController () {
    CGPoint initialOffset;
    NSInteger direction; // 0 undefined, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // retrieve current offset
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    // do we know which is the predominant direction?
    if (direction == 0) {

        // no.

        CGFloat dx = currentOffset.x - initialOffset.x;
        CGFloat dy = currentOffset.y - initialOffset.y;

        // we need to decide in which direction we are moving

        if (fabs(dx) >= fabs(dy)) {
            direction = 1; // horizontal
        } else if (fabs(dy) > fabs(dx)) {
            direction = 2;
        }

    }

    // ok now we have the direction. update the offset if necessary
    if (direction == 1 && currentOffset.y != initialOffset.y) {

        // remove y offset
        currentOffset.y  = initialOffset.y;
        // update
        [scrollView setContentOffset:currentOffset];

    } else if (direction == 2 && currentOffset.x != initialOffset.x) {

        currentOffset.x = initialOffset.x;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:currentOffset];

    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // store the current offset
    initialOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    // reset flag
    direction = 0; // AKA undefined
}

@end
```

When you start dragging, the delegate will reset the flag `direction` to "unknown" state, and store the current content offset. After every dragging move, your `-scrollViewDidScroll:` will be called. There, you decide which is the predominant direction (if this hasn't been done yet) and correct the current scrolling offset accordingly, by removing the x (or y) offset.

I tested this with the same settings you provided, only I used a `UIImageView` inside `UIScrollView` and I set up everything via InterfaceBuilder, but it should work fine. Theoretically, with this method you could replace `directionLock`, but remember that `-scrollViewDidScroll` is called many times during an action, and every time it rewrites the content offset (if the scrolling is happening in both directions). So if you leave `directionLock` enabled, you save many of the calls to `setContentOffset:` that the delegate performs.

Answer (score 7):

If i understood you right, you want to disable scrolling in the direction that has been dragged less by the user. If so, UIScrollView already offers an option to do so:

```
scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

When this option is set to true UIScrollView will handle the correct direction lock by itself.

For more information look at the documentation: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#jumpTo_15)

Comment: my friend you right but when drag on both Axis (x & y) twice scroll is working and I don't want it.